# Why does my ASP.NET application need Administrator rights to read from the registry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registry, administrator

I've looked at a couple of StackOverflow threads now. [This comes closest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349474/how-can-i-grant-my-asp-net-mvc-application-read-access-to-a-registry-key)

I'm stuck using VS2005, and .NET 2.0. The server is Win2008. Not R2.

I'm building a C# ASP.NET web application that reads information from a database that's modified by a VB6 application. The database configuration settings are stored in the registry.

I'm using the Registry.GetValue() function and it's returning a null value.

If I make the Application Pool run as Administrator, the code returns the expected value. With any other user, the ToString throws a System.NullReferenceException. I have tried the following:

1. Making the AppPool use and assigning Full Control to the following users does not work:

   1. NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
   2. NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
   3. NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
   4. A custom user in the Administrators group.
2. I cannot apply permissions to IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool because the user doesn't seem to exist. This is a [documented fault of Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account).
3. If I make the AppPool use the Administrator account, the system works.

Attached is the relevant code:

```
string root = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
string keyName = @"Software\Some\Key\Somewhere\";
string valueName = "someValue";
string fullKey = root + @"\" + keyName;
object keyValue;
try
{
    keyValue = Registry.GetValue(fullKey, valueName, "Value not found.");
    string val = keyValue.ToString();
    return val;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.GetType().ToString();
}
```

Unless it's running as Administrator, the above code always returns a System.NullReferenceException when running keyValue.ToString(). It never throws the System.Security.SecurityException.

I'm not eager to make my web app require Admin access.

Comment: Who is creating the RegKey? Open regedit and browse to your reg key. Right click => Premission, and look for the correct values.

Comment: The key is owned by the Administrators group. Administrator user, Administrators group and SYSTEM group have full control. RESTRICTED group has read access. If I add permissions for NETWORK SERVICE or any other account, and run the application pool under that user, the application still fails. It only works for Administrator. It doesn't work even as LocalSystem (SYSTEM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching under the key for the current user.  Clearly the data exists under the key for the Administrator but not for the other users.

For the service accounts that don't have a profile, HKEY_CURRENT_USER resolves to HKEY_USERS.Default.

So to make it work with service accounts, you need to add the value to

```
HKEY_USERS\.Default\Software\Some\Key\Somewhere\
```

To make it work for the custom user in the Administrators group, you need to add it to

```
HKEY_USERS\<sid>\Software\Some\Key\Somewhere\
```

where  is the SID of the custom user.

This isn't related to needing Admin access, you're just looking in the wrong place!

If the data isn't user-specific, try putting it in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Some\Key\Somewhere\
```

then all the users will normally be able to read the same value.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. My mistake.

The application also writes the settings to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, so I'll use that instead.